# Injecting Play Application for a Slick Database Service

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, guice, scalatest

This is regarding a **Play 2.3** application that I am trying to introduce Guice into.
I have the following legacy code to Guicify and I reached this point

```
class DatabaseService {
  def db: Database = DB(play.api.Play.current)
  //More code below.
}
```

This class is injected in the class under test, say com.TestA. 
When I run the test cases using a modified `OneAppPerTest` setup, I see ProvisionExceptions of the following kind.

```
Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
```

Is it because of the use of `play.api.Play.current`?
How do I fix this issue?

**Additional Info**
The overridden OneAppPerTest variant, uses the following logic

```
override def newAppForTest(testData: TestData): FakeApplication = {
    new FakeApplication(
      additionalConfiguration = additionalConfiguration,
      withGlobal = Some(globalSettings)
    )
}
```

where `additionalConfiguration` can be overridden by actual tests and `globalSettings` is where Guice is introduced within the framework

```
  protected def globalSettings = {
    new TestGlobalSettings {
      val injector = Guice.createInjector(overriddenModules: _*)

      override def getControllerInstance[A](controllerClass: Class[A]): A = {
        injector.getInstance(controllerClass)
      }

      override def getInjector = {
        injector
      }
    }
  }
```

There are other test cases with a similar setup that work perfectly fine. I am able to inject mocks, test the classes. However, every test with this DatabaseService class is failing, because I can't inject it cleanly.

Comment: If `DatabaseService` is injected, why not inject `DB` as well?

Comment: Yet to try that out. I was under the assumption that this requires `Application` to be injected too. That however, turned out to be a implicit parameter. I'll try what you have mentioned and get back to you.

Comment: @rethab DB is not an injectable property. It is more of a method that creates the Database. Database is not injectable easily because it does not have a no-argument constructor.

Comment: Maybe not `DB` directly, but this? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDatabase#Obtaining-a-JDBC-connection

Comment: This class is different in Play 2.3.x. Database is not "injectable" (provided by a non-guiced version of Slick).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to how Guice creates the objects and when. DatabaseService here had access to the current application, the current configuration. However, in my Global.scala, I had it injected before 'onStart' was actually called.
This implies that we are trying to access an application before it was properly initialized.

Making DatabaseService injection in the test class `lazy` helped avoid the error.